# RecyclerView Item specific attribute OnClick

Tags: android

I'm having hard time making this work.
I have the following scenario - when click on CardView the most inner Image should get visible. On second click should disappear. This works fine.
However I want when I select the second CardView the most inner Image to appear the the Image on the first CardView to disappear.
I have this:
1. CardView generated in XML - the cardview have 2 ImageView inside
2. RecyclerView with CustomAdapter and ViewHolder.
3. When I implement OnClick inside ViewHolder it works for each Item - on click the Image appears and on second it disappears.

However I don't know how to check on which Item the image is visible so I can hide it if another Item is clicked. In other word if I select the second I want the first to be deselected. I don't know how to handle this per position.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I was missing the point. I solved the problem simply with:

```
notifyItemChanged(position);
```

This redraws the item on this position. Since I have simple show/hide behavior with "hide" on initialization I was just using the hide state in OnBindViewHolder and the redraw did the trick.